# Not receiving email test sends

Tags: marketing-cloud

I was testing an email and i sent for testing, SFMC show me email sent but I am not receiving any email?
Any idea what is wrong?
I have already checked my spam/junk.

Comment: could be several reasons many of them are also listed here https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/265099/new-subscriber-are-not-entering-in-journey/265101#265101 most common would be they are unsubcribed or an raiseerror function that blocks the send. maybe also your senderprofile is not verified etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most common reasons why this is happening are:

1) The subscriber you are sending a test against is unsubscribed. Check in All Subs to confirm their status before you test again.

2) Your email logic contains validation errors. Preview/Check logic to confirm that no errors are being thrown.

3) SFMC's OMM is having issues. This happens somewhat frequently, but the other two options are much more likely (especially #1)

Comment: Thanks, @Jason Hanshaw. It works now, First was a problem!